# Issue in Wave while executing a dataflow

Tags: einstein-analytics

There was an error executing the 206_1 node:

> invalid field expression toDate(WaveCreateddate__c - 8*3600) for field
>   'WaveCreateddate__c': Unknown IDTOKEN: WaveCreateddate__c
>   (03K38000000TPuSEAW_02CW000000095PsMAI)

In Json File:

```
"206_1":{
    "action": "computeExpression",
  "parameters": {
    "source": "194",
    "mergeWithSource": true,
    "computedFields": [
     {
      "name": "WaveCreateddate__c",
      "type": "Date",
      "format": "MM/dd/yyyy",
      "saqlExpression": "toDate(WaveCreateddate__c - 8*3600)"
     }
    ]
  }
  },
```

Any Ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by several situations.

**Field does not exist in dataset**

This is generally caused when the field is entirely null. Fields without values will not be created in the dataset and references to those fields will error. This can be corrected by including data in the field at its source or by setting a defaultValue as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_integrate_salesforce_extract_transformation_override_metadata.htm&type=0).

**Field reference is not correct**

The Field_Name may not be correct. If the Field_Name has been manually entered in the Lens or Dashboard JSON, ensure that it is accurate. More information about Dashboard JSON is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_json.meta/bi_dev_guide_json/bi_dbjson_intro.htm).

**Field has been relabeled in XMD**

If you have used XMD to change the label for this field in the dataset, ensure that both the Lens/Dashboard JSON and the Dataset XMD match for this field. More information about XMD is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_xmd.meta/bi_dev_guide_xmd/bi_xmd_reference.htm).

**Update**

In the [SAQL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_eql.meta/bi_dev_guide_eql/bi_eql_functions_date.htm) we can see that the toDate() method is used to convert from String to Date.

*"Converts a string to a date. If a formatString argument isn’t provided, the function uses the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss."*

```
toDate(string [,formatString])
```

Comment: There was an error executing the 206_1 node: invalid field expression toDate(CreatedDate - (8*3600)) for field 'WaveCreateddate__c': Unsupported type: STRING for arg1 ('CreatedDate) of ('CreatedDate - #28800) (02K38000000TPuSEAW_03CW000000095Q2MAI)............

You have any idea???

Comment: @JamMie, Review your informaiton you are passing to make sure it works with my above updated explanation of the SAQL date function.

Comment: "206_1":{
    "action": "computeExpression",
  "parameters": {
    "source": "194",
    "mergeWithSource": true,
    "computedFields": [
     {
      "name": "WaveCreateddate",
      "type": "Date",
      "format": "MM/dd/yyyy",
      "saqlExpression": "toDate(Createddate - 8*3600)"
     }
    ]
  }
  }, -------> this my json code. i defined the Format ("MM/dd/yyyy").